# get_ticklabels() returns empty Text objects for date formatted x-ticklabels unless tight_layout() is called first

Tags: python, matplotlib

The following is modified from `matplotlib`'s [`date_demo.py`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/date_demo.html). I've removed some of their comments and added my own to indicate changes.

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook

years = mdates.YearLocator()   # every year
months = mdates.MonthLocator()  # every month
yearsFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y')

datafile = cbook.get_sample_data('goog.npy')
try:
    r = np.load(datafile, encoding='bytes').view(np.recarray)
except TypeError:
    r = np.load(datafile).view(np.recarray)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(r.date, r.adj_close)

# format the ticks
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(years)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(yearsFmt)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(months)

datemin = datetime.date(r.date.min().year, 1, 1)
datemax = datetime.date(r.date.max().year + 1, 1, 1)
ax.set_xlim(datemin, datemax)

# format the coords message box
def price(x):
    return '$%1.2f' % x
ax.format_xdata = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
ax.format_ydata = price
ax.grid(True)

# rotates and right aligns the x labels, and moves the bottom of the
# axes up to make room for them
fig.autofmt_xdate()

# My addition:
# >>> [u'', u'', u'', u'', u'', u'']                         # without plt.tight_layout()
# >>> [u'2004', u'2005', u'2006', u'2007', u'2008', u'2009'] # with plt.tight_layout()
# plt.tight_layout()
print [tl.get_text() for tl in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()]

plt.show()
```

Why do I need to call `plt.tight_layout()` to access the `x_ticklabel` text? Is there a way to access it without having to call `plt.tight_layout()`?

A similar question seems to have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41496377/matplotlib-with-qt5agg-backend-returns-empty-ticklabels), but with no real resolution.

Comment: First calling `plt.show()` and then getting the ticklabels seems to be working, so no need to call `plt.tight_layout()`. So it seems like the ticklabels are created during the actual creation of the figure. Maybe explicitly setting the x axis ticklabels based on the data, solves the problem, without the need to plot first.

Comment: This is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41122923/getting-tick-labels-in-matplotlib#41124884

Comment: I added an answer to [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41496377/matplotlib-with-qt5agg-backend-returns-empty-ticklabels/44984451#44984451) you call similar. In most cases you do not want to manipulate the ticklabels themselves. So if you can tell us the reason to get the ticklabels, there is probably a better solution than drawing the canvas first.

Comment: Call `fig.canvas.draw()` before `ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()` and it should work.

Comment: It seems I need to draw the figure before I have access to the ticklabels. Thanks all!
@ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have a weird date-format that I was trying to use and my approach required knowing all the dates (I don't show the day unless it changes; e.g. ["2017-07-10\n00:00:00", "\n12:00:00", "2017-07-11\n00:00:00", "\n12:00:00"]). I can make another post with that specific question.

Comment: @hhquark Yes, asking as specifically as possible about the *actual*  problem is always best. It ensures that you get a useful answer and don't run into things like the [xyproblem](http://xyproblem.info). Given that this question is now already 2 days old and has been marked as duplicate, opening a new question would be the way to go.